# Add features to keras time series generator for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, lstm

I'm working with time series in Keras (first time on my life). I found an useful tool of Keras to work time series, timeseriesgenerator. I'm trying to predict number solds in unit and money (2 outpus). I'd like to put some other features. THe code is like the follow:

```
from numpy import array

from numpy import hstack

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

# define dataset

in_seq1 = array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])

in_seq2 = array([15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105])

# reshape series

in_seq1 = in_seq1.reshape((len(in_seq1), 1))

in_seq2 = in_seq2.reshape((len(in_seq2), 1))

# horizontally stack columns

dataset = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2))

print(dataset)

# define generator

n_input = 2

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(dataset, dataset, length=n_input, batch_size=1)

# number of samples

print('Samples: %d' % len(generator))

# print each sample

for i in range(len(generator)):

    x, y = generator[i]

    print('%s => %s' % (x, y))
```

2 inupt arrays are sells in unit and sells in money. I have other feature on my dataset that i have to use: is_promo, a bollean variable that mean if the product is or not in promotion. 
My idea is join this feature for the day that i would predict, to see the difference between add or not a promotion for a product. 
Help please, grettings

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add another input sequence, `in_seq3`, that defines whether a promotion is active or not. I'd just encode it as a list of 0s and 1s where 0 means no promotion, and 1 means there was a promotion. So just add:

```
in_seq3 = array([0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]) #Example data
```

and instead use

```
dataset = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2, in_seq3))
```

Finally, use

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(dataset, dataset[:, :2], length=n_input, batch_size=1)
```

(the `[:, :2]` ensures that your output doesn't unnecessarily include the promotion field.)

Now that you've reshaped your data and prepared it for training a model, you need to actually train a model. For that there are many tutorials online. Good luck!